# How to send a form, then make thath a popup appears, and send the web visitor to the main page?

Tags: php

I make a contact form with html and php thth works:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST [ 'nom'];
$email = $_POST [ 'email'];
$message = $_POST['comentari'];
$to = "example@gmail.com"; 
$subject = "Formulari_contacte";

mail ( $to, $subject, $message,   "De part de:  " .$name );
?>
```

but now I want that, when the user sends the email, a popup appears saying "Your e-mail has been send" and the page takes the user to index page.

I try this:

```
echo "Su mensaje ha sido enviado";
```

But this is not useful since it brings the user to a empty page.

To make the the form i follow the instructions of this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jb7dehE9DqI

THANKS FOR THE TIME :)

Comment: There's this saying on Stack that goes like this: *"What have you tried?"* - Gawd, this is 90's technology.

Comment: I agree with @Fred-ii-. If you google a bit you can find tons of examples and starting from them you can ask for help here if you don't know how to start

Comment: Of course i google the question, but i am very new at php and i was a little bit confused with the examples thath i find in google, because, any of the examples works, so i decide to ask the question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest solution in my opinion would be to use ajax (in this case a combination of javascript and php) to submit the form and handle the response as you want (show message, redirect).

However, if you don't want to use ajax, you could also redirect the user to the home page from your form submission script with an additional query parameter that tells the home page to show the success message.

Something like:

```
header('Location: home.php?message=form_submitted');
```

Then in the home page, you can read the query string and take the appropriate action.